# Maven multiple module dependency build

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying setup this Maven build for a project and want some help to get the dependency working.

```
Project
   |--pom.xml
   |--environments
        |--pom.xml
   |--configuration
        |--pom.xml
        |--idm
               |--pom.xml
   |--other
        |--pom.xml
        |--iam-scripts
               |--pom.xml
```

`pom.xml` for `idm` module is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>saas</groupId>
        <artifactId>environments</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../environments</relativePath> 
    </parent>   

    <groupId>configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>idm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}/modules/iam3/files</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>iam-scripts.tgz</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-ext-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>other</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>iam-scripts</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                    <type>tar.gz</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/modules/iam3/files</outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>iam-scripts.tgz</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/modules</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.conf</include>
                    <include>**/*.yaml</include>
                    <include>**/*.varfile</include>
                    <include>**/*.sh</include>
                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.tmpl</include>
                    <include>**/*.tmpl.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                    <include>**/*.erb</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/modules</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.sql</include>
                    <include>**/*.service</include>
                    <include>**/*.war</include>
                    <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                    <include>**/*.gitkeep</include>
                    <include>**/*.zip</include>
                    <include>**/*.tar.gz</include>
                    <include>**/*.tgz</include>
                    <include>**/*.jar</include>
                    <include>**/*.pp</include>
                    <include>**/*.so</include>
                    <include>**/*.rpm</include>
                    <include>**/*.erb</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

`pom.xml` for `iam-scripts` module is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>saas</groupId>
        <artifactId>environments</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../environments</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>other</groupId>
    <artifactId>iam-scripts</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>
                            src/assembly/conf.xml
                        </descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/conf</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.conf</include>
                    <include>**/*.yaml</include>
                    <include>**/*.varfile</include>
                    <include>**/*.sh</include>
                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.tmpl</include>
                    <include>**/*.tmpl.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.groovy*</include>
                    <include>**/*.rptdesign</include>
                    <include>**/*.cps</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/conf</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.sql</include>
                    <include>**/*.service</include>
                    <include>**/*.war</include>
                    <include>**/*.gitkeep</include>
                    <include>**/*.zip</include>
                    <include>**/*.tar.gz</include>
                    <include>**/*.tgz</include>
                    <include>**/*.jar</include>
                    <include>**/*.pp</include>
                    <include>**/*.so</include>
                    <include>**/*.rpm</include>
                    <include>**/*.erb</include>
                    <include>**/*.md</include>
                    <include>**/*.js</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

So what I need to do is from `idm` module I need to call `idm-scripts` module build. Currently (as shown in the `pom.xml`) all it does is copying the `iam-scripts.tgz` from the repository. But say I change something within `iam-scripts`, instead of doing a manual clean build of `iam-scripts` I want to do the build from within `idm` module.

So steps I do now are:

- within `iam-scripts`, i do `mvn clean install -Denv=xxx`
- and then within `idm`, i do `mvn clean install -Denv=xxx`

How do I get `idm` build to call a clean build of `iam-scripts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me ask a question about your POM structure first:

What are ...

- `configuration/pom.xml` and
- `other/pom.xml`

... good for when both ...

- `idm/pom.xml` and
- `iam-scripts/pom.xml`

... have `environments/pom.xml` as their parent? Such leaving them out when building `idm` or `iam-scripts` anyway. (BTW, I personally consider cross referencing projects via `relativePath` across multiple levels of directories unclear and I'm avoiding such.)

In my opinion *calling* a project from within another doesn't fit into the declarative nature of POMs. Though there might be a plugin I'm not aware of that achieves that. (Oh yes, I am aware of one: GMaven[Plus]. Though I'd not recommend it here.)

To build `idm` and `iam-scripts` at once I'd use a common `pom` packaged parent POM for them (maybe your `Project` can be used for that) and add them as `<module>`s therein.

See

- [POM Reference, Aggregation (or Multi-Module)](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#POM_Relationships)
- [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit): *"Multimodule builds are to be used to group modules together in a single build."*.